# novnc: How to run websockify automatically

Tags: debian, vnc, vnc-server, websockify

Maybe someone can help me with novnc.
I want to use the novnc service, so I installed it on a debian machine with debian packages. I am able to manually establish a vnc session over a proxy server to another vnc server. But currently I have to manually start the websockify service on my proxy.

How can I start this service automatically? And if the user finished his session how do I tell the proxy server to close the session?
I only want to use novnc without the whole openstack installation.

In addition the service should run for multiple users. For example user1 should connect to proxy-ip:5901 and user2 should connect to proxy-ip:5902. So I need to start the websockify service on different ports at the same time.

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution for this question? Would be great to share your findings. Only hint I could find on this is https://github.com/kanaka/websockify/issues/134 which is a duplicate of issue/3 .. so it is possible to define some fixed routes that way.

Comment: I wrote a php scrip where I can log in with my user credentials. Then I configured a button which executes a shell command which starts the websockify with my specific values (from a database) and writes it's pid to the database. When my session is expired or I do a logout the websockify pid will be killed. Not perfect, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to launch websockify with a libvirt hook ? https://www.libvirt.org/hooks.html